# Efficient Algorithm Linear Temporal Logic to Deterministic Rabin Automata

Tags: formal-languages, formal-methods, buchi-automata

I am trying to construct an equivalent Deterministic Rabin Automata (DRA) given a Linear Temporal Logic (LTL) Formula. One (expensive) way to do this would be to construct an equivalent Non-deterministic Buchi Automata and then determinize it using Safra's construction.

I am interested to know whether there exist efficient algorithms which can 
1. Directly construct DRA from LTL without intermediate NBA construction.
2. Are there any existing tools to do this.

[This is my first question posted here. Kindly point in comment, if I missed any conventions of the forum. Thank you.]

Comment: Searching for "ltl to rabin automata" in Google gives me several results, including this: http://www.ltl2dstar.de/

Comment: @xavierm02 ltl2dstar takes the indirect way though NBAs, which the OP is trying to avoid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a very recent tool to translate from LTL directly to deterministic Rabin automata. It can be obtained here:

https://www7.in.tum.de/~sickert/projects/ltl2dra/

The page not only contains a link to the downloadable implementation, but also has link to a [technical report](https://www7.in.tum.de/um/bibdb/esparza/ltl_to_dra_techreport.pdf) that describes the construction for the translation. Apparently, a peer-reviewed paper about the construction has not appeared yet. Note that the construction is rather involved - the paper has 50 pages, and there is a reason why for many years, the detour though Büchi automata was (and somewhat still is) state-of-the-art.

Note that the computational complexity of the direct translation is not better than the one that one can obtain by translating LTL to non-det. Büchi automata and then applying Safra's method.

Comment: Another tool is https://www7.in.tum.de/~kretinsk/rabinizer3.html It is by the same authors. The page also contains many links to the papers on which the tool is based.